# Sequence contain no matching element asp.net identity external identity claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

```
externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:last_name")
```

I got following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching
>   element

(due to facebook account does not contain last name) when using asp.net identity facebook authentication to get last name using above code.

What should i do if i need to resolve this error?

Comment: Delete the question!

Comment: Don't mutilate your question. Add your answer below as an actual answer, or simply delete the question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I would catch the exception and check the Exception text and if it matches "Sequence contains no matching element" then you know you have had this error and can raise you own error if needed.